# Laravel Auth::user() Assign Custom User Model

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using my own User model class that is not derived from Eloquent. I use a database driver for authentification, which works fine.

However, Auth::user() returns a class of type GenericUser. Is there a way to assign a custom user model to the Auth class?

I tried auth config...

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'users',
    'model' => App\Models\User::class
],
```

But it doesn't work. Perhaps this functionality doesn't exist.

**Edit:**

I don't want to use Active record, I have a Data Mapper package for that. My user model looks like this...

```
<?php

class User extends Model
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, CanResetPassword;
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    protected $attributes = [
        'id' => null, 'roleId' => null,
        'email' => null, 'phone' => null,
        'firstName' => null, 'lastName' => null,
        'password' => null, 'rememberToken' => null,
        'registrationLocation' => null,
        'data' => null,
        'verified' => 0,
        'createdAt' => null, 'updatedAt' => null,
    ];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->fill($attributes);
    }
}
```

Model is extended from the data mapper package's class Entity.

Comment: can you show us your user model?

Comment: Nikola, I added some info. But the question is general. Is there any option to assign any kind of model to Auth::user ?

Comment: Yes, but your `User` model must extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` and you need to change it's namespace in config, it's under the key `model`

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I don't want to extend eloquent model.

Comment: Then you'll need to https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers